# My html code is changing when i put it on a shared directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my problem. I have to code a web application, and I want to put it on a shared file. When I open it on Chrome or IE when the app is in my personnels directories, it works, but when I open it when it's in a shared file, my interface and my code go wrong.
I've inspected the difference between the 2 options, and I discovered that :

personals files

```
<header><h1>IntraBeam</h1></header>
```

shared files

```
<header></header>
<h1>IntraBeam</h1>
<header><//header>
```

It happens to my footer too, and my Javascripts files stopped to work.
I use jQuery, and jCookies.

Comment: This kind of DOM change is normally caused by a typo in your HTML. It looks like you've got two `/` in the closing tag.

Comment: Yes, but i need to know why it add 
`/`

Comment: I don't get by what you said "personnels directories" and "shared file". Did you mean "local computer" and "shared hosting"?

Comment: Yes sry ! 
And my problem of header and footer is done, but my javascript doesn't work because i can't make an ajax to a Json in the web directory (where my html and js are  stored)